# The MPI_Sendrecv_replace function is excessively time consuming.

Tags: c, linux, performance, mpi

I called the MPI_Sendrecv_replace several times in my code. But the function behaves very strangely. In the first loop (5000 iterations), MPI_Sendrecv_replace costs about 30 seconds totally. However, in the second loop the function used only 1 second. I am very curious about the reason because I want to optimize the code. The code is running with 32 processors. The machine is one node with 4 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4620 v2.

Part of my code is here:

```
for (ishot=1;ishot<=nshots;ishot+=SHOTINC){
    ...
    for (nt=1;nt<=NT;nt++){
         ...
         MPI_Sendrecv_replace(&bufferlef_to_rig[1][1],NY*fdo3,MPI_FLOAT,INDEX[1],TAG1,INDEX[2],TAG1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
         ...
    }
    for (nt=1;nt<=NT;nt++){
        ...
        MPI_Sendrecv_replace(&bufferlef_to_rig[1][1],NY*fdo3,MPI_FLOAT,INDEX[1],TAG1,INDEX[2],TAG1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
         ...
    }
}
```

And I used the MPI_Wtime to count the time costed by MPI_Sendrecv_replace.

Comment: When you have widely varying times for essentially the same blocking communications operation to complete, the reason typically isn't that it's the communications itself taking more or less time; it's that the blocking is taking more or less time.  There's a good chance that what you're looking at is load imbalance, or that some communications partners are out of sync.  Do you see a variation in sendrecv times across MPI tasks?

Comment: Put an `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);` before the loop and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Sorry for no reply because of the school holidays. As @HristoIliev said, if I add `MPI_Barrier` before `MPI_Sendrecv_replace` in the first loop, the time cost by `MPI_Barrier` is about 30s and `MPI_Sendrecv_replace` almost do not cost time. But this situation only happens in the first loop, i.e.  there is no change when I add  `MPI_Barrier` in the second loop. One thing I forgot to mention is that the size of the NY*fdo3*MPI_FLOAT is about 16Kbytes. Is that the load imbalance problem?

Comment: Maybe you have a case of load imbalance that leads to the different MPI ranks getting out of sync in time. Because the `MPI_Sendrecv_replace` operation is synchronising and you probably have a circular chain of dependencies, then delays due to load imbalance will propagate and accumulate. Use an MPI tracing tool like Vampir (commercial software) to asses whether that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is the performance bug of MPI_Sendrecv_replace. When I replace the MPI_Sendrecv_replace with MPI_Sendrecv, the program behaves normally and the time-consuming problem disappear. I found the bug report in https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/93 and http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2010/01/11683.php

Comment: This hypothesis doesn't explain why adding a barrier reduces the Sendrecv_replace times to almost nothing, and the barrier takes 30s (!!).  I'd be willing to bet that you using MPI_Sendrecv instead Sendrecv_replace here ends up having almost exactly the same performance.  The issue here is some sort of synchronization issue, likely load imbalance; @HristoIlliev's suggestion of using a tracing tool to find out what's going on is the right way to go.  Note that freeware scalasca will identify load imbalance for you, and you can use MPE+Jumpshot as a freeware tracer.